# Jenkins - sonarQube Issue || sonarScanner Plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan, jenkins-groovy

We have integrated Jenkins with sonarQube Server using maven auto install default Scanner. Where sonar-scanner is working all fine publishing the results over sonarQube Server, but at waitForQualityGate(), getting below error.

```
Sonar Scanner Plugin - 2.9
Jenkins Version - 2.189
sonarQube Server - 7.2 (Community Edition)
```

Getting error while validating on sonar results:

```
[Pipeline] { (SonarQube Quality Gate Results)
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 1 hr 0 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] waitForQualityGate
Checking status of SonarQube task 'XYZ-123456789' on server 'my_SQ_server'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.java:349)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.java:197)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:145)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:188)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:124)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:111)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.HttpClient.getHttp(HttpClient.java:37)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getCETask(WsClient.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.checkTaskCompleted(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:215)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:159)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1726.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://FQDN/api/ce/task?id=XXXXX
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:190)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:124)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:111)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.HttpClient.getHttp(HttpClient.java:37)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getCETask(WsClient.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.checkTaskCompleted(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:215)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:159)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1726.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:36)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor647.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Validation Code:

```
stage("SonarQube Quality Gate Results"){
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
            def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
            if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                error "Pipeline Aborted due to Quality Gate failure: ${qg.status}"
            }
            print "Pipeline Quality Gate Status: ${qg.status}, proceeding with BUILD & Deploy Procedures..."   
        }
    }
```

Appreciate help with this.

Here's what we have already tried... Assuming the error is because of some proxy configuration, may be sonar-scanner is using a different proxy than the System. Already tried below:

1. In sonar-project.properties in my VCS
   http.nonProxyHosts=sonarServerFQDN (did not work)
   https.nonProxyHosts=sonarServerFQDN (did not work)
   sonar.ce.javaAdditionalOpts="-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=sonarServerFQDN" (did not work)
2. Declare an Environment Variable as

SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=sonarServerFQDN

(did not work)

Important to note that the Webhook reflects the Last Delivery properly in the Sonar Server Console.

Really appreciate help with this as stuck since a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://FQDN/api/ce/task?id=XXXXX
```

That means you haven't defined the sonarqube server.

The `sonarServerFQDN` argument should be replaced by your sonarqube server url, example :
`https.nonProxyHosts=sonar.yourcompany.com`

Comment: Hello Fauzan, thanks for your response but I have defined it... Via SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS Jenkins env variable... -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=sonarServerFQDN.company.com but still same issue

Comment: have you tried to define it directly like Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=yoursonarserver.com ?

Comment: Directly as in where do I define it ?

Comment: Still stuck in this... So the Jenkins succeeds to submit the job, but failed when asking for result using waitForQualityGate()... so somehow waitForQualityGate() is using a specific proxy... not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: don't forget to add user and password argument for the authentication . sonar.jdbc.username=
sonar.jdbc.password=

Comment: Hello Fauzan, Thanks, but not sure where are you pointing to add this. sonar-project.properties used by Scanner or on sonar.properties on sonarQube Server. Dont think that this may be causing this issue but based on your response I would check it.
Also can you suggest any means via which the waitForQualityGate  won't at all use the proxy only, as both servers can communicate all fine without a proxy

Comment: Quick update, Issue still stands unresolved. If anyone has an idea like from where does WaitForQualityGateStep pick the proxy and credential details ?

Comment: Why I am sure it's at Quality Gate Step... stack trace updated in the original post, if it helps: